# two button in bootstrap form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, formvalidation.io

I am doing the form validation using bootstrap form validation. I have two button in the particular form, one is confirm button and another one is submit button. I want to prevent the confirm button from the submission and use it as the validation button. The other button use for only submission if the form was filled correctly. If the form was accepted the confirm button is going to fade out.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I use type "button" on Confirm button it will not validate the form. If anyone has any idea please answer. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: You need to add a event on that confirm button for click and inside the click you must validate the form..

Comment: Make it simple. Disable submit button until the form validate.Otherwise if you want to do in this way just bind and event with your confirm button. for ex-. button.addEventListener('click, function(){ // do your stuff here. });

Comment: Thanks @Reddy Could u please give me some code?

Comment: Thanks @Gitesh Purbia make sense. i'll try to do what you have suggested and if there is any problems I'll update my question. Thank you so much

Comment: Which plugin are you using to validate???

Comment: Try my solution and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I changed the first button's element from an input into a button.

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button name="confirm" type="button">Confirm</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I think that the following answer is not going to work, because the bootstrap form validation does not work with type="button". I have already tested one. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to confirm button and to form. I have tested this and it's working.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm" id="confirmbutton">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and in jQuery

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#myform').submit(function(event){
    var btn = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus" ).attr("id");
    console.log(btn);
    if(btn=="confirmbutton")
    event.preventDefault();

});
}); 
</script>
```